# Having sum symbol big while being \textstyle in align environment

Tags: math-mode, align

How can I have a big sum symbol (or rather normal sized) within a align environment, but still have the limits not underneath the the symbol and on top, but to the side. So  this is what I want:

[image]

If I use `\textstyle`, the sum symbol gets also small.
The same goes for integrals too, of course.

Comment: `\sum\nolimits_{i \in B}` ?

Comment: @Au101: Yes, that is it. I had no idea this existed and I have searched for a quite a while in the internet to my defence :-).